# MobileFirst: copy files from native resources folder to native folder in Android environment

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to have my own source code at the level of an app in MobileFirst project and link it when I open it in Android Studio by configuring the `app.iml`.

This way even if I delete the native folder and then build/open it in Android Studio, I would be able to have my MobileFirst project together in Android Studio. For this I need to have the `app.iml` file copied from native resources folder to native folder when one deletes the native folder and builds it.

I know this behavior holds good when we have custom images or Android manifest file in native resources folder then these custom files gets copied into the native folder at build time. I am not able be to achieve this when I have my `app.iml` file in the native resources folder.

My friend could achieve a similar thing in iPhone environment and got it working. Please anybody help me understand if there is way that I can have my custom files automatically copied from native resources folder to native folder at build time in MobileFirst.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that use of the nativeResources folder for anything other than static files such as images is no longer considered a best practice. You should not use this folder.

The way the folder works is a simple copy procedure. As long as you mirror the folder structure of the native folder in the nativeResources folders the content will be copied to where you specified.

For example:

nativeResources\src\com\sample\customcode

Will be copied to
native\src\com\sample\customcode\